# Add related posts during question reviews

Tags: feature-request, review

When reviewing [First Posts](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts) **questions**, it would be very helpful to add the `Related` section which we can see in the right side bar of a question page like this one.

This can make reviewing questions slightly simpler and more efficient, specifically for locating dupes.